# How to use Async/Await to hold the execution?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to fetch the user Id based on the validation of some parameters. The issue is that the code is not being executed in the **right sequence**!!

#### Output is

1. KlFHdAgDUUUIKaPeObs9RiSBlOp1
2. Notifications true
3. Animals true

#### Output should be

4. Notifications true
5. Animals true
6. KlFHdAgDUUUIKaPeObs9RiSBlOp1

```
exports.bulkMsg = functions.firestore
    .document('/bulkMsgs/{bulkMsgsId}').onUpdate(async(snap, context) => {

        function processBulKMsg(onUsers) {
            anPromises = [];
            notPromises = [];

            onUsers.forEach((oneUser) => {
                var status = false;
                if (oneUser.id === 'KlFHdAgDUUUIKaPeObs9RiSBlOp1') {


                    const onNot = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(oneUser.id).collection('notifications').get().then(oneNot => {
                        if (notNumStatus === true) {
                            if ((oneNot.size >= notNumMin) && (oneNot.size <= notNumMax)) {
                                status = status ? true : false;
                            } else {
                                status = false;
                            }
                        }
                        console.log('Notifications', status);
                        return oneNot;
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log('Error getting notifications', err);
                        return null;
                    });

                    notPromises.push(onNot);


                    const allAn = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(oneUser.id).collection('animals').get().then(oneAn => {
                        if (anCountStatus === true) {
                            if ((oneAn.size >= inFarmMin) && (oneAn.size <= inFarmMax)) {
                                status = status ? true : false;
                            } else {
                                status = false;
                            }
                        }
                        console.log('Animals', status);
                        return oneAn;
                    }).catch(err => {
                        console.log('Error getting animals', err);
                        return null;
                    });

                    anPromises.push(allAn);

                    if (status) {
                        console.log(oneUser.id);
                    }

                }
            });
            return Promise.all([anPromises, notPromises]);
        }

        return admin.firestore().collection('users/')
            .where("notification", "==", "true")
            .get().then(onUsers => {
                return processBulKMsg(onUsers);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting user', err);
                return null;
            });

    });
```

Comment: From the behavior you describe one of your async operations is not being handled correctly. But there is way too much going on in this code for me to quickly scan where exactly you go wrong. Please reproduce the problem with less code to make it more likely we can help spotting what's going wrong. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Thanks for your reply. 
I have edited the original post and minimized the code. Thx

Answer (score 1):

The code is working as expected. Data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, and while that data is being loaded, your main code path continues to execute.

This code is in the main code path of your `processBulKMsg` function:

```
if (status) {
    console.log(oneUser.id);
}
```

So this `console.log` prints pretty much immediately when you call `processBulKMsg`. If you want to log the user ID later, you should only call it after the promises have resolved. Something like this

```
return admin.firestore().collection('users/')
    .where("notification", "==", "true")
    .get().then(onUsers => {
        let result = processBulKMsg(onUsers);
        console.log(oneUser.id);
        return result;
    })...
```

---

Alternatively, you can add the `oneUser.id` to the array of promises, and use it from there.

So in `processBulKMsg`, you'd do:

```
...
return Promise.all([anPromises, notPromises, oneUser.id]);
```

And then

```
return admin.firestore().collection('users/')
    .where("notification", "==", "true")
    .get().then(onUsers => {
        let result = processBulKMsg(onUsers);
        console.log(result[result.length -1]);
        return result;
    })...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Yes I had to oneUser.Id to array and also use delay after the forEach.